# Skim Dictionary backwards to find when value was updated last

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of Dictionary in which there are two key pairs of interest. One keypair is a date and the other is "investpercent", whose value changes every so often. I want to find which is the last date `investpercent` was updated. So, please consider:

```
var importedRecords = [
["low": "1.0", "date": "2018-04-25", "objective": "2.0", "savings": "2.0", "high": "2.0", "expenses": "1.0", "investpercent": "3.0"], 
["low": "1.0", "date": "2018-05-25", "objective": "2.0", "savings": "2.0", "high": "2.0", "expenses": "1.0", "investpercent": "3.0"], 
["low": "1.0", "date": "2018-06-25", "objective": "2.0", "savings": "2.0", "high": "2.0", "expenses": "1.0", "investpercent": "4.0"], 
["low": "1.0", "date": "2018-07-25", "objective": "2.0", "savings": "2.0", "high": "2.0", "expenses": "1.0", "investpercent": "4.0"], 
["low": "1.0", "date": "2018-08-25", "objective": "2.0", "savings": "2.0", "high": "2.0", "expenses": "1.0", "investpercent": "5.0"], 
["low": "2", "date": "2018-09-26", "objective": "2.0", "savings": "2.0", "high": "4", "expenses": "1.0", "investpercent": "5.0"]
]
```

Now, note that `investpercent` changed last in "2018-08-25", and the value I am interested is "5.0". My idea goes along the lines:

```
var lastentry = importedRecords.suffix(1)
var lastdate: String = ""
for record in importedRecords {
    if record["investpercent"] == lastentry["investpercent"] {
        lastdate = record["date"]
    }

}
```

But I am stuck trying to convert that Slice of Array into a proper Dictionary.

- How can I skim this array so to detect the date when `investpercent` was last updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, and it uses [`zip`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541125-zip):

```
let reversedRecords = importedRecords.reversed()
let zipped = zip(reversedRecords.dropFirst(), reversedRecords)

if let twoDictionaries = zipped.first(where: {$0["investpercent"] != $1["investpercent"]}),
    let date = twoDictionaries.1["date"] {
    print(date)
}
```

It prints `2018-08-25`

Comment: It works, thank you! Could you point me to zip() documentation please?

Comment: Sorry to bother again, this code has a syntax that I never saw before. What is that comma at the end of the `if let` line? What it's separating?

Comment: It just separates multiple conditions, it is like having `&&` : a logical **AND**